# Converted Macbook Disk to Dynamic. Is there a fix for this?

Tags: macos, mac, boot, boot-camp

I realize this question has been asked before, but I have other questions too.

Firstly though, I have a MacBook with dual boot Mountain Lion and Windows 8. I tried to partition the hard drive from the windows side. I was asked if I wanted to convert my disk to dynamic, but the prompt said that I would still be able to boot from windows. Now, even windows won't boot I am getting the blue "a problem has occurred =(" screen.

so is there a way to reverse what I have done?

In the mean time, I found that Windows 8 has a recovery environment with a command prompt, which I have been able to use to grab all my important files from the windows partition. But I also have some files on my OSX desktop that I need, but can't find a way to get to. How can I access the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally, I was able to finish the job and get my files out of the mac partition.

[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) wasn't able to restore the disk to it's previous state, but it *was* able to make a disk image of the partition in question, and save it to an external drive. Finally, I was able to open the disk image using [OSForensics](http://www.osforensics.com/) and save the important files to disk on another machine.

Case Closed =)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [blog post](http://www.allroundgeek.com/2011/05/saving-my-data-convert-dynamic-disk-to.html) on someone who did the same thing and how he recovered it.  He used [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to convert the drive back to basic.

Comment: I came across that post, and other similar ones earlier today, but I'm a little confused by TestDisk. It seems other people have been able to just press "Analyze" and then when the result is ready, choose "Write". For some reason though, the program is freezing at the end of the search and not producing the option to write.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant help you with that.  Just sharing what I came across.

Comment: it's starting to look like I can just crank out a .dd image file and mount it on another comp.. but thx anyways